# cannot add data atom package on atom editor

Tags: python, package, atom-editor

Why cannot I add data atom package to my atom editor? It asks me to add Git for windows first.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMEjP.png)

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but have you installed git on your machine?

Comment: no. do i neccessarily have to?

Comment: If the atom package is stored as a git repository, you will need git in order to get it. The error explains exactly what you need to do.

Comment: gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.33.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.33.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "install" "--runtime=electron" "--target=2.0.11" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--arch=x64" "--ensure"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\HP\.atom
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok  " . please help.